# Memory size increasing every time I update application on same device

Tags: android, android-memory

The problem is whenever I update my application on my device the size of the internal memory increases to the size of the application.

I have a single application which runs on tablet associated to the application. i.e. only that application will run on that tablet and it will be a boot application of the tablet. Due to this feature I have added code to update the application internally within the application. I have written code to download the application from my server and update the application with the new version. Also I have written some code to check the used memory and total memory of the internal memory on the device.

Note: There is no external memory i.e. there is no sd-card available for this operation.

The scenario is.

Step 1) I download a new version of the application within the application and update it.

Step 2) After updating when the application restarts I have written code on a splash screen to delete all the old application data. The old data consists of application cache, stored images, downloaded apk and clearing folders created by the application.

Step 3) I reboot the device to check the working functionality. Now after the application starts I check the memory, suppose previously used/total memory was 0.45GB/5.08GB. Now I follow step 1 again.

Step 4) After rebooting when I check for the internal memory size, surprisingly the memory size has increased by 120MB which is the size +-1MB of my application size. i.e. the old size of the internal memory used/total 0.45Gb/5.08Gb the increased size of internal memory after the reboot and updating the application is 0.57GB/5.08GB

I have tried to check the data/data folder but its size also remains the same but the size of internal memory increased to the size of the application. I do not know what is increasing the size of the internal memory.

Is there any place or thing that OS is keeping in the application size data or am I missing something in the application which is causing the increased size of the internal memory to the exact size ?

**EDIT**

Code to delete videos which I am keeping in specific path

```
/**
     * Method to delete all the videos from SD card on startup
     * */
    public static void deleteAllVideos() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                File dir = new File(directoryPath);
                try {
                    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        files[i].delete();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                dir.delete();
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Code to delete APK from the device

```
    public static void deleteFile() {
        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath();
        File folder = new File(imagePath);
        try {
            File[] filenamestemp = folder.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < filenamestemp.length; i++) {
                if (filenamestemp[i].getAbsolutePath().toString()
                                .endsWith(".apk"))
                    filenamestemp[i].delete();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Deleting Application Cache and cached images from memory

```
/**
     * Method to clear application data
     * 
     * @param Context
     *            context of screen
     * */
    public static void clearApplicationData(Context context) {
        File cache = context.getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            File cacheDir = null;
            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                    android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                cacheDir = new File(
                        android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        Global.CACHE_DIRECTORY);
            } else {
                cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
            }
            if (cacheDir.exists()) {
                File[] filesList = cacheDir.listFiles();
                for (File file : filesList) {
                    file.delete();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```

These are the deleting codes which I am using to delete all the contents that I am creating in internal Memory including application cache

Comment: Show relevant code please.

Comment: @F43nd1r What kind of code you are expecting?

Comment: Especially the code which should delete the old content but apparently doesn't, but everything related might help.

Comment: @F43nd1r I have added codes that used to delete files which I am creating in memory other than that I am not creating any kind of files in the internal memory

Comment: Does the size only increase after a restart? Have you checked that you have the permissions to delete all those files and directories? Try to check the result of `File.delete()` to see if it returns always true..

Comment: Yes size increase when I restart device and update application again. But never mind I have found the solution. I will post it very soon

Comment: All who are downvoating please let me know why you are doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully found out the issues related to storage size increase problem.

The problem was due to OS was storing state of the application in LOST.DIR folder in internal storage directory.

This folder stores info about application/device so that if any loss is happen it will be recover in the next boot of the application.

I have written code to delete all files in this folder. After delete my memory is recovered. Deleting these files is not harmful for our application or Device. Its like recycle bin of windows from where we can recover deleted files according to use.

During this testing I also found that as we close device or reboot the device the state of our application is saved in LOST.DIR folder. Reason is that application is singleton and device is not properly shutdown i.e. if we shut down device directly, without using power button. This causes OS to save state of our application.

The whole theory is given here([all-you-need-to-know-about-lostdir](http://thesundaycoder.blogspot.in/2014/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-lostdir.html)) which is also as follows

**What is LOST.DIR ?**

The Lost.dir is a system folder. Its a place where the Android OS places files that were recovered during a system boot up (ie when you turn on your phone). It is analogous to the 'Recycle Bin' under Windows OS. The files which are stored inside this directory are often recoverable. Most of the times you won't find anything at all in LOST.DIR directory.

**What files are stored in LOST.DIR ?**

If you were saving files and suddenly the phone turned off, or maybe you pull the SD card out when files were being written to it - the Android system places copies of those files in LOST.DIR directory so it can try and recover them on the next boot (next time the system starts up). The files in the process of copying are also renamed. So if you find wierdely named files in the folder, don't be surprised as they are only renamed versions of erstwhile files present on your device.
    Files may end up stored in LOST.DIR folder due to following reasons :

1) Abruptly pulling out SD card from Android phone

2) Interruptions while downloading files on Android device

3) Sudden freezing of Android device operating system

4) Switching off the device while some read-write process is carrying on.

**How do I recover files from LOST.DIR folder?**

In order to stop permanent loss of files from LOST.DIR folder in Android, you have to quickly recover missing files before your Android smartphone memory space is overwritten by some new data. Therefore use of some pertinent LOST.DIR Android recovery tool is recommended. Yodot Android Data Recover, Recuva are a couple of examples which worked for me.

**Can I delete the contents of LOST.DIR ?**

In order to save precious memory space its completely normal to delete the contents of LOST.DIR as it only acts as a recycle bin. You can also delete the LOST.DIR folder itself but it will reappear the next time the system boots up. When your Android system throws up a message saying 'Preparing external SD card' its actually checking the contents of LOST.DIR, and if it fails to locate the directory, it creates one.

**Necessary Guidelines :**

1) Avoid abrupt removal of Android device's memory card while transferring data to/from the system.

2) Backup your images or other files to some other device.

3) Use authentic android antivirus software to protect yourself from virus-attack.

Comment: how you find out those files and how you deleted those files dynamically ?

Comment: You can do a normal file search as you do for image and etc. in lost.dir folder and can delete file as you delete image etc.